# Google cloud storage - permission denied exception

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to access cloud storage bucket ,of my appengine project from another appengine  project .

Since the cloud storage bucket is present in another project , I provided permission as [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/).

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dutch-barber/1.379022461794999395/barber/bems/service/__be_service_resource.py", line 182, in dispatch
    uploadToGcs(featuredImage,file_url)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dutch-barber/1.379022461794999395/cloud_barber/utils.py", line 118, in uploadToGcs
    writable_file_name = files.gs.create(filePath,mime_type=file.content_type,cache_control='no-cache')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/gs.py", line 331, in create
    return files._create(_GS_FILESYSTEM, filename=filename, params=params)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 650, in _create
    _make_call('Create', request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 255, in _make_call
    _raise_app_error(e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 213, in _raise_app_error
    raise PermissionDeniedError(e)
PermissionDeniedError: ApplicationError: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

the link which you mentioned [in your question](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage) has been deprecated.

Check the newer version of Google Cloud Storage Client Library and  [install it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/download). Then, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Developer Console to edit permission of your bucket. You will be able to add a project and set it as a owner / reader / writer

Comment: That I already did. I set new project as owner for this bucket . Actually I want my new project to write contents on this bucket .Also tried to edit acl of this bucket and added my new project's Service Account Name with write permission through gsutil . Even then it is showing permission denied error

Comment: Are you using File API or Google Cloud Storage Client Library ? The first is deprecated.
Does gsutil getacl gs://bucketName  shows correct permissions?

Comment: Any chance you are using gsutil as a different user? If so add yourself as a developer to the Project in Cloud Console containing the bucket.